# Is there a standard notation for the sets of incoming and outgoing edges from a vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I'm writing up an algorithm involving some graph theory and am looking for a standard way of denoting the set of incoming and outgoing edges from a vertex. If my vertex is called $v$ and graph is $G$, I want to denote

$$ \{ e \in E(G) : e = (v, w), w \in V(G) \}. $$

This is sort of cumbersome to write out in an algorithm and I would like to define my own notation like in($v$) and out($v$) or something, but I don't want to do that if there is already a standard way of writing it.

Comment: The notation I have seen is $\delta^+(v),\delta^-(v)$ for outgoing/incoming edges. I am not sure if that's the standard.

Comment: @rmccloskey: Use $E^+(v)$ for outgoing and $E^-(v)$ for incoming edges.