# Defining outgoing edge set of a graph

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, notation

This is pretty much the same question as [Is there a standard notation for the sets of incoming and outgoing edges from a vertex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553926/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-the-sets-of-incoming-and-outgoing-edges-from-a) which does not have an answer, but does have comments.

As I understand, one comment is referring to the degree, and $\delta^+(v)$ is the number of edges, not the set of edges. The other comment mentions to use $E^+(v)$, which I have not been able to find/see in any textbooks, compared to say $N^+_G(v)$ to represent the neighborhood of $v$.  This seems like there is a standard notation for the set of vertices connected to the outgoing edges of $v$, but not one for the edges themselves?

I was trying to formulate the notation for the set of outgoing edges as:

(Existing basic definitions)

$G := (V,E,w)$

$V := \{v_i,\dots,v_n \}$

$E := \{e_{ij}, \dots,e_k ~| ~e_{ij} = (v_i,v_j) \}$

(Then outgoing edge set from neighborhood)

$ E^+_G(v_i) := \{ e_{ij} | ~v_j \in N^+_G(v_i) \}$

Question; is this definition reasonable as is, or does it seem too verbose if the symbol is already well enough defined (or is there an error)?

Side question; Is the use of $N^+(v)$ special in any way, or if $E^+(v)$ meant outgoing edges, why not use $V^+(v)$ for outgoing vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Modern Graph Theory" by Bollabas, the chapter on "Flows in Directed Graphs" gives a helpful notation for this:

Given two subsets X, Y of V, we write $\vec{E}(X,Y)$ for the set of directed X-Y edges:

$\vec{E}(X,Y) = \{\vec{xy} \in \vec{E} : x\in X, y\in Y \}$

If $S$ is a subset of $V$ containing $s$ but not $t$ then $\vec{E}(S,\bar{S})$ is called a cut separating $s$ from $t$.... If we delete the edges of a cut then no positive-valued flow from $s$ to $t$ can be defined on the remainder.

From the original and linked question, the idea of using $\delta^+$ was only questionable because I had seen it defined as the "minimum out-degree".  Based on all of these references:

1. "Graduate Texts in Mathematics: Graph Theory, J.A Bondy, U.S.R Murty"
2. "A first course in Graph Theory. Gary Chartrand and ping Zhang"
3. "Classes of Directed Graphs. Jorgen Bang-Jensen, Gregory Gutin"
4. "Graph Theory by Diestel"
5. "Modern Graph Theory by Bollabas"

I don't think it would be good to redefine a ubiquitous term within the same context.

Answer (score 2):

For my graph theory class, we used $\delta^+(X)$ to be the set of edges leaving $X$ and $\delta^-(X)$ to be the set of edges coming into $X$ ($X\subseteq V(D)$ and can be a singleton). For your side question, I'm not sure what you mean by "outgoing vertices". I have never seen direction added to vertices.

Comment: For "outgoing vertices" I mean "outgoing neighborhood".  Do you have a reference for the $\delta^+$ ?  The 3 or 4 graph theory books I have define it all the same: $\delta^+(D)$:= minimum outdegree. "Graduate Texts in Mathematics: Graph Theory, J.A Bondy, U.S.R Murty"

Comment: Two more references (so all 3 say the same), $\delta(G)$:= minimum degree of G "A first course in Graph Theory. Gary Chartrand and ping Zhang" and $\delta^+(D)$:= minimum out-degree of D "Classes of Directed Graphs. Jorgen Bang-Jensen, Gregory Gutin"

Comment: You can still define the minimum out/in degree of a graph that way. For instance Graph Theory by Diestel uses d(v) as the degree of a vertex and d(G) as the average degree of a graph. No I don’t have a book reference but Modern Graph Theory by Bollabas may use this notation.

Comment: Well yes, Diestel uses d(v) for degree, and $\delta(v)$ for minimum degree. I will check out Bollabas, thanks.

Comment: Modern Graph Theroy by Bollabas was helpful.  It actually shows $\delta$ as minimum out-degree, like every other reference I found, which helps me conclude this is almost surely not the answer that would be clear as it reassigns an existing well known notation. It does have another notation though that did answer the question, so I appreciate the reference.